# How can I use a cursor with a common table expression in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, cursor, common-table-expression

I have a cursor in need to use with a CTE and I'm getting an error every time I run it.

```
DECLARE @retVal VARCHAR(max),
        @curDist VARCHAR(3),
        @curDealer VARCHAR(6)
        @dist VARCHAR(3)
SET @dist='304';

WITH dist (DSCD,PREV_DSCD,level) AS (

    SELECT d.DSCD,d.PREV_DSCD, 0 AS level FROM scdst AS d WHERE d.DSCD = @dist
    UNION ALL
    SELECT d.DSCD,d.PREV_DSCD, level + 1 FROM scdst AS d
    INNER JOIN dist AS d2 ON d.DSCD=d2.PREV_DSCD
)

DECLARE distListCursor CURSOR FOR SELECT DSCD FROM dist

OPEN distListCursor
FETCH NEXT from distListCursor INTO @curDist
```

Error message:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 17
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DECLARE'.

I've used this recursive CTE before but never with a cursor, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: I closed the question, but the short answer is that the `with` goes after the cursor declaration.

Comment: My fault I missed that one.  Thanks.